# i am doing the fusion of RGB and flow .But i get TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

the code is:

```
parser.add_argument('score_files', nargs='+', type=str)
score_npz_files = [np.load(x) for x in args.score_files]
print('score_npz_files:',score_npz_files)

score_list = [x['scores'][:, 0] for x in score_npz_files]   
label_list = [x['labels'] for x in score_npz_files]
```

i input:

```
python tools/eval_scores.py ucf101_bninception__rgb_checkpoint.pth.tar ucf101_bninception__flow_checkpoint.pth.tar --score_weights 1 1.5
```

and the print:

score_npz_files: [119547037146038801333356, 119547037146038801333356]

<class 'list'>
(2,)

the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tools/eval_scores.py", line 33, in 
score_list = [x['scores'][:, 0] for x in score_npz_files]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

i am doing TSN, but i get this error.I dont know how to handle it?Can you help me?Thank you very much!!

Comment: What does `[:, 0]` mean, when you have numbers as part of the list, as shown in `score_npz_files: [119547037146038801333356, 119547037146038801333356]`?

Comment: Pretty clear.  The 'npz' file does not contain what you think.  It looks like it has two numbers in it, and you're expecting it to have a dictionary.  Now, do you realize that numpy does not know how to unpack a .tar file?

Comment: i input the ‘ucf101_bninception__rgb_checkpoint.pth.tar‘ and ’ucf101_bninception__flow_checkpoint.pth.tar‘ as the score_files. i just print the score_npz_files: [119547037146038801333356, 119547037146038801333356]@shahkalpesh

Comment: Do you mean I need to unpack tar first? @TimRoberts

Comment: Maybe the format of the input file should be .npz ?

Comment: `np.load` loads npz files.  If the tar contains an npz file, then yes, you need to untar it first.

Comment: you are right！！Thank you very much！！@TimRoberts